# Is it possible to disable Same Origin Policy on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge, same-origin-policy

Same Origin Policy blocks me from accessing the document of cross domain iframe in Edge browser, I wonder is it possible to disable it?

I checked the settings in `about:flags`, nothing seemed related to SOP.

I also checked Windows Group Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Microsoft Edge, still nothing related to SOP.

Is there any other settings, or startup parameters to disable SOP for Edge?

Comment: I think this has been asnwered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1020612/can-the-same-origin-request-policy-be-disabled-in-microsoft-edge), or is this not the answer you're looking for?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Yeah, I saw that answer, but it was answered 2 years ago, and Edge is a new browser and involves frequently, so I think now something may have changed.

Comment: @Jasen him wanting to do that doesn't directly imply that he wants to write bad code in a production environment. Maybe he wants to test something or do something else entirely, don't judge :P